# how to pass email in query param in get request in angular

Tags: angular

I want to send email as query param in get request. How can i send it??
Right now my function looks like this

```
     getCandidateInfo(email: any): Observable<any> {
let params = new HttpParams().append("email", email)

  return this.http.get<any[]>(this.candidateInfo,{params})
}
```

At present it looks like this

[image: It shows email]

I want it like

[image]

How can i get this..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution coming to my mid is

```
return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.candidateInfo}?${email}`)
```